# How to check if an element has two specific child?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How to check this with XML LINQ?

I need to check if parent has child1 and child2 both. This should return true:

```
<parent>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2></child2>
</parent>
```

These are false:

```
<parent>
    <child1></child1>
</parent>
```

or

```
<parent>
    <child2></child2>
</parent>
```

Comment: `bool hasOneOrMoreOfBoth = xml.Elements("child1").Any() &&  xml.Elements("child2").Any();`  to restrict to 1 of each use `.Count() == 1` instead of `.Any()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an XML file with a `root` element and a collection of `parent` elements, such as:

```xml
<root>
    <parent>
        <child1></child1>
        <child2></child2>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child1></child1>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child2></child2>
    </parent>
</root>
```

You can get the `parent`s containing both exactly one `child1` element and exactly one `child2` element by using the following code:

```cs
var xmlFile = @"[...Path to your xml file...]";

var root = XElement.Load(xmlFile);

var parents = root.Elements("parent");

var eligibleParents = parents
    .Where(p => p.Elements("child1").Count() == 1 
        && p.Elements("child2").Count() == 1);
```

`parent` would contain:

```xml
<parent>
  <child1></child1>
  <child2></child2>
</parent>
<parent>
  <child1></child1>
</parent>
<parent>
  <child2></child2>
</parent>
```

`eligibleParents` would contain:

```xml
<parent>
  <child1></child1>
  <child2></child2>
</parent>
```

The expression

```cs
p.Elements("child1").Count() == 1 
    && p.Elements("child2").Count() == 1
```

returns true if the `parent` (`p`) element has exactly one `child1` and exactly one `child2` children element.